# My loop GUI keep getting error does anyone know the problem?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

does anyone know whats wrong with my code? it keep getting error output in java GUI
the loop 2 and loop 3 getting error after debug, and i dont know whats wrong

```
 private void butActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    String input1 = txtInput.getText();
    String input2 = input1.toLowerCase();
    char[] word1 = new char[input2.length()];
    char[] word2 = new char[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++) {
        word2[i] = (char) (97 + i);
    }
    int[] x = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < word1.length; i++) {
        input1[i] = input2.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word1.length; j++) {
            if (word2[i])==word1[j]) {
                x[i]++;
            }

        }

    }
    txtOutput1.setText(Arrays.toString(word2));
    txtOutput2.setText(Arrays.toString(x));
}
```

Comment: What errors you are getting exactly?

Comment: @Pshemo the line after the loop for in line 11 and line 15

Comment: And what is at line 11 and 15 (we don't know if there are some other lines before what you posted which may affect line numeration)? Also you still need to [edit] your question and include error message (if it happens at compilation) or exception stacktrace (if it happens while running your code).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 1):

The first problem:

`input1` is a string, but with `input1[i] = input2.charAt(i);` you are treating it as an array - this is not allowed in Java.

From your logic I think the corresponding line should be

```
word1[i] = input2.charAt(i);
```

---

The second problem: on the line

```
if (word2[i])==word1[j]) {
```

there is a closing parenthesis to much (after `word2[i]`), the line should read

```
if (word2[i]==word1[j]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`input1` is a String variable and therefore immutable, which means it can only be assigned a new value and can not be changed otherwise.

The following line causes a problem:

```
input1[i] = input2.charAt(i);
```